# Unique Rows that match a specific criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, t-sql

My data is Microsoft Office 365 Mailbox audit logs.

I am working with 14 columns, incorporating names, timestamps, IP addresses, etc.

I have two tables, lets call them **EXISTING** and **NEW**. The column definition, order and count are identical in the two tables.

The data in **Existing** is (very close to!) Distinct.

The data in **New** is drawn from multiple overlapping searches and is not Distinct.

There are about millions of rows in **Existing** and hundreds of thousands in **New**.

Data is being written to **New** all the time, 24x7, with about 1 million rows a day being added.

~95% of the Rows in **New** are already present in **Existing** and are therefore unwanted duplicates. However the data in **New** contains has many gaps, there are many recent rows in **Existing** that are NOT present in **New**.

Want to select all rows from **New** that are not present in **Existing**, using **Invoke-SqlCmd** in Powershell.

Then want to delete all the processed rows from **New** so it doesn't grow uncontrollably.

My approach so far has been:

Add a **[Processed]** column to **New**.

Set **[Processed]** to 0 for all existing data for selection purposes. New rows that continue to be added will have **[Processed] = NULL**, and will be left alone.

**SELECT DISTINCT** all data with **[Processed] = 0** from **New** and copy to a table temporary table called **Staging**. Find the oldest timestamp (**[LastAccessed]**) in this data. Then delete all rows from **New** with **[Processed] = 0**.

Copy all data from **Existing** with **[LastAccessed]** equal to or later to above time stamp across to **STAGING**, adding the column **[Processed] = 1**.

Now I want all data in **Staging** where **[Processed] = 0** and there is No duplicate.

Nearest concept I can come up with is:

```
SELECT MailboxOwnerUPN
      ,MailboxResolvedOwnerName
      ,LastAccessed
      ,ClientIPAddress
      ,ClientInfoString
      ,MailboxGuid
      ,Operation
      ,OperationResult
      ,LogonType
      ,ExternalAccess
      ,InternalLogonType
      ,LogonUserDisplayName
      ,OriginatingServer
FROM dbo.Office365Staging
GROUP BY MailboxOwnerUPN
        ,MailboxResolvedOwnerName
        ,LastAccessed
        ,ClientIPAddress
        ,ClientInfoString
        ,MailboxGuid
        ,Operation
        ,OperationResult
        ,LogonType
        ,ExternalAccess
        ,InternalLogonType
        ,LogonUserDisplayName
        ,OriginatingServer
HAVING Count(1) = 1  and Processed = 0;
```

Which of course I can't do because **[Processed]** isn't part of the Select or Group. If I add the Column **[Processed]** then all lines are unique and there are no duplicates. Have tried a variety of joins and other techniques, without success thus far.

Initially without **[Processed] = 0**, the query worked, but returned unwanted unique lines from **Existing**. I only want unique lines from **New**.

Clearly due to the size of these structures efficiency is a consideration. This process will be happening regularly, every 15 minutes ideally.

Identifying these new lines then starts another process of Geo-IP, reputation, alerting, etc in PowerShell....

Comment: Are you able to show some sample data? I think CTE is the best approach for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thought the performance of the following would be horrid, but it is OK at ~27 seconds....

```
SELECT [MailboxOwnerUPN]
      ,[MailboxResolvedOwnerName]
      ,[LastAccessed]
      ,[ClientIPAddress]
      ,[ClientInfoString]
      ,[MailboxGuid]
      ,[Operation]
      ,[OperationResult]
      ,[LogonType]
      ,[ExternalAccess]
      ,[InternalLogonType]
      ,[LogonUserDisplayName]
      ,[OriginatingServer]
  FROM dbo.New
  WHERE [Processed] = 1 and
        NOT EXISTS (Select * From dbo.Existing
                          Where New.LastAccessed = Existing.LastAccessed and 
                                New.ClientIPAddress = Existing.ClientIPAddress and
                                New.ClientInfoString = Existing.ClientInfoString and
                                New.MailboxGuid = Existing.MailboxGuid)
GO
```